# Where does user settings get stored in a Java application?

Tags: java, settings

We have this Java application which we use for our production work (we do not have the code for it).

It is installed on a Windows 2008 Server under different user names; when a user logs in and starts the application, there are lots of settings which needs to be modified every time.

I cannot figure out where these settings are stored in the backend (I would like to change the settings to a default value so the user does not have to change them every single time).

The app is installed in Program Files (I cannot find any .properties files and the existing XMLs does not have the settings which I am looking for).

Comment: Your question is absolutely impossible to answer with the information you've given. There are any number of ways a Java program can store user preferences, and without seeing the actual code, there's no way for anyone to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for your input #MarsAtomic. I thought that maybe there is a way to find where the settings are stored :)

Comment: There *is* a way, but not from anything you've posted here. At this point, I'd recommend contacting the original developer to get the source code or decompiling the class files (if that is permitted under your contract).